vim fireplace beginners guide
I'm just starting out with Clojure. So far I've edited .clj files and executed them by running lein repl, (load-file "test.clj") and (foo). This worked so far.
Mind I haven't created a leiningen project. I simply use lein repl because the standard repl doesn't even support cursor up to recall the last command.
Now I want to up my game a bit and run clojure from within neovim. fireplace was suggested in the first spot both on clojure.org and on clojure-doc.org. Thus I've installed that.
Now consider this code:
(ns leintest.testns)

(defn foo [] "foo")

(foo)

(+ 2 3)

which I put into leintest/src/leintest/testns/test.clj. As the file structure suggest, this is now a leiningen project created with lein new app leintest.
However, nothing works. Sometimes I could get (+ 2 3) to print 5 when I run :Eval with the cursor on it, but not even that worked when I created this example. I also couldn't run (foo) in the repl. The testns namespace simply isn't there.
Funny thing, when I load test.clj into the repl outside of a leiningen project, I can actually call (leintest.testns/foo).
While the README on github for fireplace isn't exactly short, I can't shake the feeling that it is not aimed at beginners like me. Most of it simply doesn't make sense to me.
Is there anywhere a beginner friendly guide how to get started with fireplace? I'm not hellbend on fireplace though. I simply went with it because it was the first suggestion. If there is another plugin that is more beginner friendly I'll gladly swap for it.
Here are some questions:
I run lein repl from a separate terminal. Isn't there a way to start the repl from within vim?
How can I get (foo) and (+ 2 3) to be evaluated with :Eval (or perhaps another method)?
Do I even need to have (foo) in the file just in order to run the function foo?
How does reloading work? I sometimes have the feeling that my edits have no effect. But when I kill the repl and restart it, I seem to get some reaction to my edits. I doubt that this is the appropriate workflow.
I would also expect that since I have a repl open in the leiningen project, I would be able to evaluate my functions directly in the repl. That never worked for me. Only when I loaded the file manually outside of a leiningen project.

Probably this cheat sheet would be a good starting point: https://gist.github.com/nblumoe/5450099 , otherwise you can always open the online help with :help fireplace. Also, remember to always setup cider-nrepl in your project: https://docs.cider.mx/cider-nrepl/usage.html

Have you connected to the proper REPL?  e.g. on starting a project it will pick
up a .nrepl-port file from the working directory. You can start the REPL from
inside the editor with the vim-salve plugin.  Unless to reload the file with
clojure (e.g. a reload workflow) or fireplace (there are commands to reload in
the docs) means, there are no automatic reloads.  There are on the other hand
things, that are "hard" to reload, but not the things you described so far.
